# Majority elements in an array (n/3)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

The code below for the majority elements in an array  works for `n/2` times of elements, but not for `n/3` times. Can anyone help me?

```java
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> majorityElement(int[] a) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        int flag=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = i; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (a[i] == a[j])
                    count++;
            }
  
            if (count > a.length/3) {
                arr.add(a[i]);
                flag=1;
            }
        }
        if (flag==0)
            return new ArrayList<>();
        
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine when i try it. What exactly is the input you give and your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing all those elements which are at index lower than `i` in the second for loop. To count the frequency of a number you need to equate it with all the elements present in the array, even to itself as well if you start with `count = 0`.
Here is the modified version:

```java
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
                if (a[i] == a[j])
                    count++;
  
            if (count > a.length/3)
                arr.add(a[i]);
        }
        
        return arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse from i=0 to n and j=0 to n inorder to calculate frequency of each element, also it would be better if you use a HashMap to solve it, time complexity right now is O(n2), by using hashmap you can solve it in O(n)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/majority-element/